# How to implement security to WCF service to restrict the service to consume(not allow to consume service) at client side for other users

Tags: c#, wcf

i am created WCF service and consumed that service at client application(web application) it is working fine.
but I am trying to implement security to WCF service to not consuming/restrict  the service at client side for other users,i am using basicHttpBinding.

please find the client web.config code below,

```
<bindings>

  <basicHttpBinding>

    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_WCFService" />

  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost/ WCFService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IWCFService" contract="WCFServices.IWCFService" behaviorConfiguration="endpointCredentialsBehavior"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_IWCFService" >
   </endpoint>
</client>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi! Please try to make your question more targeted. It is not clear what you need? Do you need authentication? Would it be enought to restric access over Server Firewall Rules? Is "HTTP" is a must have?

Comment: Hi,Yes I need authentication and HTTP is must.

Comment: read here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650862.aspx#Authentication and here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg185971.aspx